# Should I add “will” in this after-clause?

Tags: tense, conditionals

**Examples:**

Example 1

> If I become a member of the rock band after tonight's audition is finished, I will practice playing the guitar with them tomorrow night.

Example 2

> If I become a member of the rock band after tonight's audition **will** be finished, I will practice playing the guitar with them tomorrow night.

**Question:**

Because the audition is in the future, I wonder whether I should add "will" in that after-clause in example 2?

Comment: No, you should not. You could say _after the audition has finished_, though. You are talking about a time in the future when the audition will be in the past.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your reply. Are both "after the audition has finished" and "after the audition is finished" correct?

Comment: Yes, I think both would be acceptable.

Comment: This is "first conditional" structure. You can look it up

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of how to use tenses in conditional sentences. Example one is correct, where first part is in present and the second part is in future.

"If I become a member of the rock band after tonight's audition is finished," this whole is considered as one condition on which the second condition is dependent.

Comment: I think the term "conditional tense" here is confusing.  English doesn't have a conditional tense in the proper tense (and the term "conditional tense" is used in some older grammars to refer to constructions with "would" specifically, which isn't applicable here).  I think you should just say "a classic example of how to use tenses in conditional sentences".

Comment: @rjpond I guess you are right. I will rephrase it.